# Accessing structure through pointers [c]

Tags: c, data-structures, pointers, pass-by-reference

I've got a structure which holds names and ages.
I've made a linked-list of these structures, using this as a pointer:

```
aNode *rootA;
```

in my main. 
Now i send **rootA to a function like so

```
addElement(5,"Drew",&rootA);
```

Because i need to pass rootA by reference so that I can edit it in other functions (in my actual program i have two roots, so return will not work)

The problem is, in my program, i can't say access the structure members.

```
*rootA->age = 4;
```

for example doesnt work.

Hopefully you guys can help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your question but it looks like the type of `rootA` in the last sample is `aNode**`.  If so the reason why it's failing is that `->` has higher precedence than `*`.  You need to use a paren to correct this problem

```
(*rootA)->age = 4;
```

See full [C Operator Precedence Table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

If the type of `rootA` is instead `aNode*`.  Then you don't need to dereference in addition to using `->`.  Instead just use `->` directly

```
rootA->age = 4;
```

Comment: Wow, that does it perfectly. Thanks, i had no idea it worked that way. Also, getting an answer in 36 seconds thats completely right is awesome. I have to wait 11min to select it as the right answer, lol!

Comment: Precedence mistakes are common faults in today's programming.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to pass a pointer to the `rootA` variable, and not dereference it twice.

```
addElement(5,"Drew",&rootA);
```

Comment: my copying abilities are to blame, fixed in the question.